# Exponent in a plotmath expression

Tags: r, plot, plotmath

I would like to have the following, for example in a ggplot2 label:

```
ylab(expression((hat(beta)^(2))(x)))
```

but without the parentheses around the `hat(beta)^(2)`. But if I remove the parentheses, then the `(x)` goes up to the exponent.

Is there grouping in these expressions? Or invisible parentheses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you would like?

```
ylab(expression(hat(beta)^(2)*(x)))
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did not think of using * because I was thinking "function of" and not "multiplying" but I guess they are the same.